# Can't use external-check in Haproxy

Tags: linux, haproxy

I'm trying to use the option external-check in haproxy, but after service restart in log I see:

```
Dec 30 10:41:34 1 haproxy[89540]: [WARNING]  (89540) : config : 'external-check command' will be ignored for proxy 'primary' (requires 'option external-check').
Dec 30 10:41:34 1 haproxy[89540]: [WARNING]  (89540) : config : 'external-check path' will be ignored for proxy 'primary' (requires 'option external-check').
```

content of haproxy.cfg:

```
global
     log 127.0.0.1   local2
     log /dev/log    local0
     log /dev/log    local1 notice
     chroot /var/lib/haproxy
     stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
     stats timeout 30s
     external-check
     user haproxy
     group haproxy
     maxconn 4000
     daemon

defaults
    mode                    tcp
    log                     global
    option                  tcplog
    retries                 3
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

listen stats
    mode http
    bind *:7000
    stats enable
    stats uri /

listen primary
    bind 192.168.57.200:5000
    option external-check
    external-check path "/usr/bin:/bin"
    external-check command "/bin/ldapHealthCheck.sh"
    option httpchk OPTIONS /master
    http-check expect status 200
    default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
    server patroni1 192.168.57.133:6432 maxconn 100 check port 8008
    server patroni2 192.168.57.134:6432 maxconn 100 check port 8008
    server patroni3 192.168.57.136:6432 maxconn 100 check port 8008
```

Why option external-check is still required when I have this parameter added in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is the Problem but your HAProxy is working in a chroot Jail (under global chroot /var/lib/haproxy).
So if you want to get your external-check working, you need to add at least bash in your chroot.
Check this thread: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/external-check-and-chroot/2150/13
hope this may helps you :D